# What wires can I use to make an extension of LCD?

Tags: lcd, cable, laptop-repair

I want to put main part of laptop into a drawer, and put display on a desk.
[Like this.](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj315LFkPzJAhVm4XIKHZX_AA4QjRwIBw&url=%2Furl%3Fsa%3Di%26rct%3Dj%26q%3D%26esrc%3Ds%26source%3Dimages%26cd%3D%26cad%3Drja%26uact%3D8%26ved%3D0ahUKEwj315LFkPzJAhVm4XIKHZX_AA4QjRwIBw%26url%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Flifehacker.com%252F5874600%252Fbuild-a-computer-into-your-desk-for-easy-upgrades-hidden-cables%26bvm%3Dbv.110151844%2Cd.bGQ%26psig%3DAFQjCNGPSNKqJtOhH2bPQG4Ytgi7YyHt7g%26ust%3D1451308747758977&bvm=bv.110151844,d.bGQ&psig=AFQjCNGPSNKqJtOhH2bPQG4Ytgi7YyHt7g&ust=1451308747758977)

So I need to make wire extension of laptop's LCD wire (extend length), which connects LCD display with motherboard.

Can I use any wires (from usb-cable for instance) or should I use cable like this (Is this right cable for extension ?):
http://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/2015-lcd-flat-flex-extension-cable_60287969599.html?spm=a2700.7724857.29.3.Yz5U7T&s=p

Comment: Hmm. "Min.Order Quantity: 1000 Piece/Pieces"

Comment: Can you elaborate on the end goal of the extension as there may be an easier method to do what you are trying to do?

Comment: The answer will depend on a number of things.  Do you want to extend or replace the existing cable (2 extra connectors plus wire to fit somewhere that typically has no free space)?  Do you know that this is the appropriate type of wire and connectors (some laptops use ribbon cable)?  Nobody can answer this without knowing more about your laptop and what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @fixer1234 updated

Comment: @Eric Johnson upated

Comment: You can't use just any cable, and the one you linked to is 12" long.  This will require a custom cable, with the right connectors at each end for your hardware, the right connection wiring, the right gauge of wire, in the length you want, it will likely need shielding and some wires may need a specific configuration like being twisted, it will need a protective jacket and strain relief at the connectors, and you probably want connectors designed to handle the stress.  It would make more sense to modify the laptop and screen so that a standard external cable can be used between them.

Comment: fixer1234 I ment this: slice original cable in two pieces and connect them by extension. So on both tips of long wire would be original connectors.

Comment: 1) Are you sure that what's in your laptop is not a ribbon cable?  2) How did you plan on connecting bare wires to each end of the extension cable, getting each connector to the right place, and making reliable and secure contacts?  3) What does that extension cable buy you over cutting the wires one at a time and soldering a long piece of wire between the ends?  4) #3 isn't likely to be satisfactory because there are considerations besides getting current to flow from A to B.  You will have losses, noise in, noise out, crosstalk, etc.  A lot of design goes into a simple thing like a cable.